How should I repair 100 year old subflooring?
I am installing, or trying to, vinyl plank flooring in our bathroom.  It looks like two layers of vinyl sheeting were installed on top of the original hardwood flooring.  Well, some of the hardwood had water damage because the sheeting install was not done well or maintained well.  So... I ripped it out and found that some of the diagonal subfloor planks are loose and have water damage.  The joists are 24 inch on center and some of the subfloor planks look like they may not be on the joist, and are below the other planks by an 1/8 to 1/4 inch.  So, before I start ripping the subfloor out and get in over my head, what is a good way to repair these loose and "below grade" planks?  I do have basement access to the underside, I just have to cut out some 12 inch ceiling tiles...
I noticed some possibly helpful info on this thread: Securing 3/4" T&G OSB over old plank subfloor
But still not sure about the planks that have a lot more deflection because they may not end directly on top of the joist.
Thanks.

Usually if a section of plank does not end on a joist, you replace it with a longer plank or add/sister a 2x to the joist to hold the plank.  Any planks that have rot are replaced.

Vinyl planks and tiles like a flat solid sub floor.  They can usually handle small less than 3/16 difference in floor height over a few feet, and they do like bouncy floors.  Once the planks are fixed, can add OSB/plywood sheets to strengthen the floor if needed.

If the end of a subfloor plank won't end on a joist when replaced, put some blocking between the joists.  If you have vertical gaps between planks and joists, screw them down.

In case you haven't used it before, be aware that loose vinyl planks require a very smooth and clean surface. Even small bits of dirt can cause a corner of a plank to lift slightly higher than its neighbours, and that corner will eventually begin to wear out. The last time I installed it, I sanded all the joints between the sheets of plywood underlay to ensure that they were perfectly even.

The damaged subfloor planks are replaced and blocking or sistering with 2x lumber is used if a plank is not resting on a joist. You can do this from above and avoid tearing out the ceiling below. Just remove enough of the old planks to have room to work. Then reuse the planks that are suitable and replace the bad with good.
Then cover the subfloor with 1/2 inch plywood. ( NO OSB). Over that lay either 1/2 inch or 1/4 cement board, (like durock). The direction perpendicular to the plywood. (I tape the seams with Butyl tape to keep it water sealed.) The thickness would depend on how thick the old flooring was. You want to match that the best you can.
This give you a multilayer base for the LVP, with the cement board being water resistant. This method also mitigates the unevenness that was part of the plank of subfloor.
You can then lay the LVP. In kitchen and baths, I caulk the baseboards and cabinets and any fixtures to the flooring, so any water that may leak or be puddled will not seap over the edge of the flooring.  ( This helped greatly in the aftermath of the hurricanes here in Fla. No water got past the LVP and caused any other damage. )

I removed the existing 2x that was attempting to support the short planks, threw screws into the other end of those planks from the basement because they happened to run under the tub.  Unfortunately, I was not able to left those sagging planks enough so I found this 2.7mm stuff called Luan (spelling?) and added that under the 3/4 inch CDX I had on hand.  This helped match the unevenness.  It's not perfect, but I hope that after I put a few screws in and check for flatness, it will be close enough for the LVP.  If I remember correctly, LVP can handle 1/4 inch over 6 feet?

@crip659.  To continue, once I finish the demo of the old flooring, and cut the CDX to fit, I hope that what I have on hand will be adequate enough to finish the job.  If I still need to level the flooring a bit more, how does leveling compound work on the plywood?

LVP is more forgiving than most people think.  a 1/4 inch drop over 6 feet is nothing.  The issue would be a hump in the middle of a 6 foot run.  In that case 1/4 inch is about the max, because you are asking the LVP to bend and still keep it's seams together.  Minor unevenness in the floor is ok. The surface does not need to be billiard table smooth.
